# trying to get my video to always fill me container

Tags: jquery

hello all wonder if someone might be able to help/

i have a video inside a div, the width and height of the div variable

```
<div class="videoSlpash">
    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0" >
      <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/splash.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/staticbacbkground.jpg" class="headerImage imgFullWidth" alt="">
    </video>
</div>
```

and the size of the video is 1600x800

now i am going round in circles here trying to come up with the maths to get this working but if i right it in english someone may be able to help

what i need to happen is if the container is lets say:

1600 x 900 - it need to 100% the height of the video or it wont fill the container
1000 x 400 - it needs to be 100% width so that it fills the container

the video always has to fill the container to if its ratio height is not high enough to fill the container make it 100% height, if its ration width is not wide enough to fill the container it will be 100% width

really hope this make sense

i will be using JQuery to do what i need just need some pointers

below is where i am up to and i know its all wrong

```
function resizeDiv() {
  vph = $(window).height();
  nav = $('.headerWrap').height() - 10;
  vpw = $(window).width();
  hei = vph - nav + 4;
  vh = $('#video_background').height();
  vw = $('#video_background').width();


  $('.videoSlpash').css({'height': hei + 'px'});
  $('.videoSlpash').css({'padding-top': nav + 'px'});



if ((vpw > 1600) || (hei < 800)) {
    $('#video_background').css({'height': 'auto'});
    $('#video_background').css({'width': '100%'});
    console.log('bg 1');
    console.log('Height '+hei);
    console.log('vpw ' +vpw);

} else if ((vpw < 1600) || (hei > 800)) {
    $('#video_background').css({'height': '100%'});
    $('#video_background').css({'width': 'auto'});
    console.log('bg 3');
    console.log('Height '+hei);
    console.log('vpw ' +vpw);

} else if ((vpw > 1600) || (hei > 800)) {
    $('#video_background').css({'height': '100%'});
    $('#video_background').css({'width': 'auto'});
    console.log('bg 2');
    console.log('Height '+hei);
    console.log('vpw ' +vpw);

} else if ((vpw < 1600) || (hei < 800)) {
    $('#video_background').css({'height': '100%'});
    $('#video_background').css({'width': 'auto'});
    console.log('bg 4');
    console.log('Height '+hei);
    console.log('vpw ' +vpw);


  }
```

odd

Comment: I think you need to be using `&&` to get your desired result. Your last two `else if`s will never be hit. Also use `>=` and `<=` because the width and height could be exactly those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

sorry one of those days i fixed it myself

```
   function resizeDiv() {
      vph = $(window).height();
      nav = $('.headerWrap').height() - 10;
      vpw = $(window).width();
      hei = vph - nav + 4;
      actualH = (800 / 1600 * vpw);

      $('.videoSlpash').css({'height': hei + 'px'});
      $('.videoSlpash').css({'padding-top': nav + 'px'});

      if (actualH < hei) {
        $('#video_background').css({'height': '100%'});
        $('#video_background').css({'width': 'auto'});
      }

  else {
    $('#video_background').css({'height': 'auto'});
    $('#video_background').css({'width': '100%'});
  }
}
```